# SendGrid CORS Response in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to implement SendGrid for emails and I'm running into some issues.  I found the example [here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/USE_CASES.md#with-mail-helper-class) for c# and set up a quick desktop example based on this.  I create a WPF application and put this in a button handler:

```
    async void BtnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var apikey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENDGRID_API_KEY");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apikey);

        var from = new EmailAddress("<<my email>>", "me");
        var to = new EmailAddress("<<test receiver email>>", "you");

        var msg = new SendGridMessage();
        msg.SetFrom(from);
        msg.AddTo(to);
        msg.SetTemplateId("<<my template id>>");

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

        MessageBox.Show($"Status: {response.StatusCode}\n\nHeaders:\n{response.Headers}");
    }
```

However when I click the button I get this:

[image: Result]

I did go to the url on that header as well as found it elsewhere [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/).  However that link is talking about browser based which this is not, plus it says to use one of the libraries which I am (I'm using the c# NuGet package).

What am I doing wrong?  I will eventually put this on a web server in my AWS lambda API so I guess if I have to do that for testing I can but was hoping to do some testing and setup on desktop to familiarize before I move it over to the server...

Comment: CORS only applies to browser code.  The status is unauthorized.  Are you sure your API key is being set?

Comment: Agh, sorry, no it isn't, now I have to figure out why...  When I go to command prompt and type 'set' it shows me that variable with the appropriate value... not sure why it isn't recognizing in the program though...

Comment: How are you setting the environment variable?  Also, *when* did you set it?  Was it set *after* you launched Visual Studio?  VS launches applications with the set of env. variables it had when VS itself launched.  If you set the variable after VS was launched, then VS doesn't have it, and consequently, neither will your application.  This is a guess at what is happening though.

Comment: Ok, yeah that was it.  I set it after starting VS so it wasn't recognized by VS...  Restarted VS and it was there and everything worked.  *facepalm*.  Sorry, I'll leave this in case anyone else has the same facepalm moment but if mods want to delete feel free.

Comment: I will submit that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the environment variable after starting Visual Studio, you need to restart VS.  VS launches applications with the set of environment variables it had when VS itself launched. If you set the variable after VS was launched, then VS doesn't have it, and consequently, neither will your application.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error and the error did not make any sense what went wrong.

I found out that i was missing the `From` and `FromName` in my configurations. so in my code, I was hitting SendGrid API with `From` and `FromName` as `null`.

This was my case, you can check out if you're missing out these parameters or other parameters like `To` email. or `API_KEY` or something of sorts.

Hope it helps!